# React Native not displaying correct image

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a slideshow where the user can play them in a default or random order and cycle through them by pressing a button. The problem comes when the user has chosen random mode; pressing the button still increments the currentIndex variable, but for some reason images[currentIndex] does not change.

```
const SlideshowScreen = (props) => {
const settings = props.route.params.settings;
const [images, setImages] = useState(settings.random ? props.route.params.images.sort((a, b) => 0.5 - Math.random()) : props.route.params.images);

const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('currentIndex', currentIndex, images[currentIndex]);
}, [currentIndex])

const newImage = () => {
    if (currentIndex + 1 >= images.length) {
        console.log('done');
    }
    else {
        setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
    }
}

return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
            <Image
                style={styles.image}
                source={images[currentIndex].path} key={images[currentIndex].id} />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => newImage()}>
                    <Text>Next image</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

)
}
```

On some clicks of the button this happens, and on others it doesn't. How is this happening? Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: when does the user changes the settings to random? my guess is that the images didn't change after changing to random settings. Try using effect on the random settings to update the images state.

Comment: That is done in a previous page and passed in via props, so if settings.random is true then the images will be sorted in a random order, and if not will be in their default order. When I console log the images I can see that they are in a random order, but for some reason some button clicks don't change the image even though the currentIndex has been incremented.

Comment: what is the image path? a url? you've already confirmed that it's not just loading?

Comment: Yes a url. I have an array of the form images = [{id: 1, path: require('../assets/images/image1.png'), title: 'image 1'}, {id: 2, path: require('../assets/images/image2.png'), title: 'image 2'},...] which I pass in. The problem is that when I press the button to change the image and log in the console, currentIndex has increased but images[currentIndex] seems to be using the old value for currentIndex.

Comment: can you tell me the reproduction steps? e.g. show slideshow, set settings to random, close slideshow, etc..

Comment: The user chooses to set the order to either default or random, and then clicks on a button to play the slideshow. This button takes the user to a page where the first image is displayed and they can click a button to make the image update to the next one in the array.